# What mean of the `BIN`, `UN`, `ZF`, and `G` means in MySQL WorkBench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

When I create a table, I add the rows in table, but don't know the `BIN`, `UN`, `ZF`, and `G` means.

I know the `PK` is primary key, the `NN` is not null, the `AI` is auto increment, but how about the others here?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Those means:

`BIN`: binary (if dt is a blob or similar, this indicates that is binary data, rather than text)

`UN`: unsigned (for integer types)

`ZF`: zero fill (rather a display related flag)

`G`: generated column

You can also get that info from the tooltip that shows up on mouse hover over the header:

[image]